# Get all keys from map in Golang Template without use vars

Tags: templates, go

I have something map by . (point symbol) and I want to print just every key.
I know we can use some:

```
{{ range $key, $value := . }}{{ $key }}{{end}}
```

But I cant use var, because I use Docker Compose file which problem withi symbol $.

How I can print all keys without use vars?

Answer (score 2):

Extract the keys and sort them, then feed them into the view, as iterating a map has indeterminate order anyway (which you don’t want).

```
import "sort"

var m map[int]string
var keys []int
for k := range m {
    keys = append(keys, k)
}
sort.Ints(keys)
```

Within a range loop, use . to refer to the items being ranged. A new context is created for that loop.

```
{{ range . }}
  {{ . }}
{{ end }}
```

However I suggest you fix the problem with using the symbol $, you will want to use that. That sounds like the wrong use of Docker Compose files - you could put your golang templates into separate files, or into the go source files themselves if you want a single binary deploy.

Comment: Thanks, I’ve ammended the above to sort keys first to get predictable order too.